# Changing Owner before editing causes an error

Tags: lightning-experience, case, fls

Can I have a little help understanding this problem.

In this scenario I always recieve an error that looks like a Field Level Security (FLS) problem but I am accessing as a System Administrator.

On the Case object the case's default owner is the queue "Customer Services".  As a member of this group I choose to change the owner to myself and then edit the record on the same tab the I always receive the error below:

```
Review the following errors

> No Access to field Name, Either the field was removed from the entity or access to this field was removed.

Review the following fields
>
```

Please note, no field names are listed above except "Name" (which doesn't existing on Case Record).

If I edit the record first and then change owner, there are no problems. If I close the tab and re-open it there are no problems.  For reference there are no validation rules, triggers etc on this object.  I've checked FLS on Account, Contact and Case all access is right.

Thanks

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMM6QAO&title=users-encounter-error-no-access-to-field-isprimary-either-the-field-was-removed-from-the-entity-or-access-to-this-field-was-removed looks like a bug that will be fixed in the summer release.

Comment: Certainly sounds similar. Thanks